# callThrough not working when creating spy using createSpyObj

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

It seems the `and.callThrough` does not actually run the original implementation, when the spy object is created using `createSpyObj`. As an example, let say I have an Angular service that has the following helper method:

`user.service.ts`:

```
class UserService {

    getFullName(first: string, last: string): string {
         return first + ' ' + last;
    }
}
```

In the specs, I create a spy using `createSpyObj`:

`user.service.specs.ts`

```
const userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>('UserService', ['getFullName']);

// ....

beforeEach(() => {

    userServiceSpy.getFullName.and.callThought();
    const test = userService.getFullName('test1', 'test2');
    console.log(test);   // < = = = = = ISSUE: test is undefined! WHY ???
});
```

How can I make the `getFullName` function run as implemented in the main class? 
(I don't want to stub, or call a fake function, but somehow use the main function implementation when calling the `getFullName`).

I tried overwriting the function prototype with the original:

```
userServiceSpy.getFullName.prototype = UserService.prototype.getFullName;
```

Second attempt:

```
userServiceSpy.getFullName = UserService.prototyp.getFullName; // This is a compile error.
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. You're calling through *to the spy object* there's no real implementation to invoke. If you don't want to stub or call a fake function, why createSpyObj? You seem to be trying to test a mock, which is pointless.

Comment: How can I use the main implementation when calling `getFullName` of the spy object?

Comment: callThrough is generally used when you spied on the real implementation to start with. It's unclear what you're actually trying to test here, so it's hard to say what an appropriate solution might be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know why you insist on deleting the headings. It makes it more readable, it separate where the actual question vs the example or description is. So ppl won't get confused  what to answer. Please bring em back. Thanks for the other edits though

Comment: The headings don't help at all with readability, they just get in the way of scanning through the question - you don't need an **Example** heading immediately followed by *"As an example"*, for example, or a **Question** heading immediately followed by the one sentence with a question mark, or (perhaps most obviously) an **I tried** heading immediately followed by *"I tried..."*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need to use `callFake` and use the function implementation from the prototype as follows:

```
userServiceSpy.getFullName.and.callFake(UserService.prototype.getFullName);
```

Comment: That's baffling, though, because the "fake" implementation you're calling is *actually the real one*. That's such a footgun to leave behind for the next person. In your example, you can just *call the real implementation*, the spy object is totally redundant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the Service (and the spies) have other functions as well. And this `getFullName` method is kind of a helper method. Other methods, also call `getFullName` so the point is I wanted to mock the other methods, while keeping the main implementation of `getFullName`

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea. Again: without context, though, it's hard to say what the good idea would be.

Comment: Late to the party but Google led me here: A potentially-valid case is when you want to test an abstract base class that has a method with code. You can mock an instance of this base class with `createSpyObj()` and use the method outlined in this answer to do so without having to create a stub derived class or rely on a real derived class to do so. @jonrsharpe